# Current capacity of batteries wired in parallel

Tags: batteries, current, amperage

I'm wondering what would happen to the mAh when I connect 2 5000mAh batteries in parallel. Would the mAh over all be 10000mAh?!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMFqpO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Assuming they are the same battery, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Connecting voltage sources in parallel increases AH and connecting in series increases voltage. These increase of voltage and current are additive.

You should not connect different types of batteries or cells. Same type batteries or cells should not be connected in parallel if they possess different voltage.

Answer (score 2):

**Parallel.**  The capacity adds up.  If the batteries are identical, then no more comments are needed.  In general, the batteries have to have the same chemistry and voltage.  E.g. connecting a lithium-ion battery in parallel with lead-acid battery is a bad idea.

**Series.**  The voltage adds up.  The capacity is equal to that of the smallest battery.

Answer (score 0):

The total available energy (in watt-hours) doubles whether the batteries are in series or parallel.

Consider a battery that operates at voltage V and delivers current I.

Two such batteries in parallel can deliver the same voltage V, but at twice the current 2I. Power is then V*2I. The same two batteries in series deliver current I but at twice the voltage 2V; thus, the power is 2V*I.

You choose which arrangement to connect the batteries—series or parallel—based on whether you want twice the voltage or twice the current of either battery by itself.